# How do I install Visual Studio on Pop!_OS linux with WINE?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wine, debian-based

I was attempting to install Visual Studio 2022 with WINE. At first I was told that I needed to install .NET 4.6 or higher. I followed the instructions and installed .NET 4.8. Then I tried to do it again. I was then told that I needed to install WINE Mono. I followed some instructions on askubuntu and installed WINE Mono. Now when I try I get an error saying

```
010c:err:mscoree:mono_assembly_preload_hook_fn Failed to load L"C:\\windows\\Microsoft.NET\\assembly\\GAC_64\\PresentationCore\\v4.0_4.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\\PresentationCore.dll", status=3
```

I tried searching on the internet however, it seems no-one has posted about this error before as I couldn't find any results for the error I got.

Comment: My advice would be that if you work closely with .NET, running it on Linux is a mess. It might be better to use a Windows virtual machine and run Visual Studio on it, which is how I used to do it during my college days.

Comment: The resource you found on [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/195144/how-can-i-install-visual-studio) is really old, is not relevant as of today. There are no solutions to run VS2022 onto Linux environment, unless using a VM.